# find command does not work the way around

Tags: find

If I do:

```
find / -name '*image*'
```

it outputs all files and dirs containing 'image' in their names:

```
[...]
/usr/share/mime/image/x-sun-raster.xml
[...]
/usr/include/qt5/QtGui/5.11.1/QtGui/private/qimage_p.h
[...]
```

so, logically, if I do:

```
find / ! -name '*image*'
```

or

```
find / -not -name '*image*'
```

it should exclude all files and dirs containing 'image' in their names. Unfortunately, this is not the case; it only works for files but not for dirs:

```
[...]
/usr/share/doc/qt5/global/template/images/Qt-dark_gradient.png 
[...]
```

what have I been missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an escape character `\` before the exclamation mark. To find all files and directories containing "image" in their names, your command should look like this:

```
find / \! -name "*image*"
```

As the man page states, you need to protect the (!) from the shell:

> ! expr True if expr is false.  This character will also usually need
>   protection from interpretation by the shell.

As for your second try, `find / -not -name '*image*'`, the `-not` flag is not POSIX compliant, so if you are using a POSIX compliant shell it will not work. For information on the `find` command, refer to the [Find Manual Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), and refer to [This Article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766270/what-is-posix-compatible-mode-in-linux) for more information on POSIX compliance.

Comment: If the shell expanded `!` for the OP, the resulting command would most likely be syntactically incorrect. Your "improved" command prevents the shell from interfering, granted, but it doesn't prevent `/usr/share/doc/qt5/global/template/images/Qt-dark_gradient.png` from appearing in the output. It looks like the OP's shell didn't expand `!`. Your answer gives some valid advice on `find` usage in general, but it doesn't really make the difference for the OP and it doesn't address the real issue (see my answer).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, you are correct, I forgot about directories mea culpa. Your answer actually addresses the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

`-name '*image*'` tests the last component of the path.

<sup>(I don't believe you got `/usr/share/mime/image/x-sun-raster.xml` from your first command. It doesn't match.)</sup>

In this path

```
/usr/share/doc/qt5/global/template/images/Qt-dark_gradient.png
```

the last component is `Qt-dark_gradient.png`, therefore

- `-name '*image*'` fails,
- `! -name '*image*'` succeeds.

---

You probably want `-path`, it matches against the whole path.

```
find / ! -path '*image*'
```

Excluding directories with names matching `*image*` is possible with `-prune` but not as straightforward. In some circumstances it may be a good idea because it avoids testing (possibly many) child objects that would be excluded by `! -path '*image*'` anyway.

```
find / \( -type d -name '*image*' -prune \) -o \( ! -name '*image*' -print \)
```

This will be useful if you have a massive tree under some `*image*` directory (or directories). Otherwise simple `! -path '*image*'` will be OK; the delay from this sub-optimal approach will be negligible.